# Incident over the pacific

Tags: tcas

I read this from the new CNN.com: [Two planes nearly collide over Pacific](http://cnn.com/video/data/2.0/video/us/2014/05/16/erin-air-traffic-control-error-responsible-for-near-mid-air-collision.cnn.html).

The death toll would amount more than the [Tenerife](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tenerife_airport_disaster)'s one if things went actually wrong.

Kevin Townsend tells more in his post: [Two Weeks Ago, I Almost Died in the Deadliest Plane Crash Ever](https://medium.com/medium-long/c2f8d68a917c).

### My question is:

Can the passengers ask for some compensation (damages or whatever) due to the event?

Comment: What damages? All this is is media speculation about a crash that did not happen.

Comment: I dont see how you could claim compensation for _not_ crashing. Mind you in the USA.......

Comment: `Kevin Townsend` _invents_ `more in his post` fixed

Comment: I didn't tell asking compensation for *not crashing*. An extreme diving is frightening and passengers may not stand that. There should be someone else responsible for the incident and its eventual consequences.

Comment: I certainly hope not or the next time the pilots will be less inclined to take decisive action, thus aggravating the situation. The system worked, an error managed to slip through but was caught before it could turn into a disaster. 600 feet is not in any way an "extreme dive" unless you're 500 feet above the ground. Sure it might be frightening but I'm guessing that people would rather ride a little roller coaster than cutting it too close.

Comment: Assuming that the pilot has reacted properly (which is my opinion too) implies the ATC is to blame in the very case. I think of "Moral damage", a legal concept mostly known in countries whose legal system is based on the *`Code Napoléon`*: mainly civil suit but not criminal charge.

Comment: Not sure why the down votes here. Whether or not we agree there was an event, there is a single solidly defined question and it is directly related to a fight on an airplane. Are we saying (by voting down) that we don't like questions of airline responsibilities? If you hover your mouse over the down arrow itself, the tooltip states "the question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful." The only part of that which might apply is "not useful" and I think it is.

Comment: I voted to close this question because it is, in essence, a legal question.  The fact that the answer would be primarily opinion based is somewhat secondary...  Either way I don't think this question is a good fit for this site.

Comment: @CGCampbell While a site is in beta, the scope of the site is not well defined. Downvotes indicate that there is *something* about this question that the community finds not useful as a question on this site. Highly downvoted questions are something that are taken into consideration when clarifying scope as the site moves through beta.

Comment: CNN did it again. Absolutely no proof about a plane crash, and even their headline admitted it ("Plane drops 600 feet in 60 seconds"... since when has that been an emergency decent???)

Comment: If anyone's still interested, check out [The Reality Behind the “Hawaii Near Collision”](http://www.nycaviation.com/2014/05/near-miss-near-hawaii-didnt-happen/) over at NYC Aviation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not a lawyer. None of this should taken as, or construed to be legal advice.

Looking over United's [Contract of Carriage](https://www.united.com/web/format/pdf/Contract_of_Carriage.pdf) upon which their passenger bill of rights are based, I found this paragraph:

> UA shall not be liable for any death, injury, delay, loss or other damage of whatsoever nature (hereafter referred to collectively as “damage”) arising out of or in connection with carriage or other services performed by UA, unless such damage is proven to have been caused by the sole negligence or willful misconduct of UA and there has been no contributory negligence on the part of the Passenger

One of the planes involved in the incident to which you refer was a UA flight. They were flying per ATC guidance, therefor there was no "sole negligence or willful misconduct" etc.

That being said, to answer your given question, **yes** the passengers can *ask* for compensation. They are unlikely to be granted any by the airline, as that would set a bad precedent (not a legal precedent, but one that might affect them legally down the road). They are under no obligation to make compensation, as they fulfilled the contract between themselves and the passengers. The passengers were safely delivered to their destination with little to no delay.

In my personal opinion, the airline owes nothing to any of the passengers, even for "mental anguish" as the total deviation from flight path was well within the amount that could be seen or felt due to [severe turbulence](http://www.navyaircrew.com/blog/2009/08/30/light-moderate-or-severe-turbulencehow-are-they-defined/).

Comment: Thank you for the answer! You've overlooked the "ATC" side of the question: Can it be also sued or just an eventual sanction from the NTSB will do and basta?

Comment: I haven't done any research into the ATC regulations concerning culpability of actions. In the US, almost anyone can "be sued". The NTSB (as far as I know) is not a sanctioning body. It would perform an investigation, and submit a report, then some other body (FAA?) would take some action. I would imagine the ATC is already looking into the event and if two controllers put the aircraft on the same path and altitude ( I don't believe this is true ) there will be ( at a minimum ) training or retraining of controllers.

Comment: "They were flying per ATC guidance, therefor there was no "sole negligence or willful misconduct" etc." - How do you know this?

Comment: "the total deviation from flight path was well within the amount that could be seen or felt due to severe turbulence" - How do you know this? Even if the total deviation *was* within that which could be felt due to severe turbulence, is that the relevant test when determining damages or standard of care in a negligence case?

Comment: I know this because the authors description corresponds to severe turbulence according to the guide I linked. Actually, upon further inspection, it wasn't even as bad as severe turbulence. Severe (usually) ends up with injuries to passengers not seatbelted in. http://www.aviationlawmonitor.com/2014/05/articles/airlines/us-airways-flight-735-airlines-obligation-to-compensate-injured-passengers/ talks about lawsuits. Since the author is a US citizen, traveling domestically, he cannot sue, without proving negligence.

Comment: Lastly, there are yet to be published any real, official, findings by anyone. There is nothing in ASRS (I looked). Until and unless there are published findings, proving anything will be difficult. The author SAYS the oncoming plane was at a FL used by east-bound aircraft, but no official findings corroborate that claim, yet.

Comment: @CGCampbell Are you saying that there is no possibility of negligence if the deviation is less than what would be caused by severe turbulence? That would be a new negligence test that I don't think has ever been applied by a court as far as I can tell.

Comment: @CGCampbell Also, how do you know that they were flying per ATC guideance and therefore no sole negligence or willful misconduct?

Comment: @CGCampbell You mention the "total deviation from flight path". What *was* the total deviation from flight path?

Comment: @articuno, as I stated in my answer, I'm not a lawyer, it wasn't legal advice. I'm not going to get drawn into a series of comments or answers that can turn it into such. As soon as the question was put on hold, I should have stopped commenting. My bad, and it won't happen again.